# Can you identify the military uniform on the man in this photo?

Tags: military, 20th-century, identification, uniform

I found this photo in a box I inherited from my grandmother. The photo is on heavy card-like stock, but there is no writing or any markings on the back.  My grandparents were born in Germany, but came to the USA in the 1920s and lived for some time near Peru, Illinois, and then later settled in Chicago.  I have no idea if this photo is from Germany or from the USA.  Any help identifying anything at all about this photo would be greatly appreciated.

(click to enlarge each)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The sabre most likely indicates he was either an officer, or in the cavalry.

Comment: This does not look to me like a post-1920's American photo.  I would guess it is of a  generation or 2 older than that of your grandparents'.  I would guess that the older male figure might have been a policeman or fireman, or other civic functionary, whose ceremonial uniforms in Germany in the late 19th century had swords.   The fancy cuff decoration made me think of a naval uniform, but the lack of lace and insignia and badges and so on on the chest makes that seem unlikely.

Comment: Agreeing with kimchi, this pic seems to depict other people than you describe here? Can you identify any person shown positively? From where in Germany did the grandparents come?

Comment: Wrong sword for Imperial German Navy.  Got one on the shelf over my head at the moment - black leather scabbard with brass fittings, lion's head pommel, slight curve to blade.  Note also sleeve stripes are not German navy pattern and that the gent sports plain edged shoulder straps, also not navy.  Agree that this is some sort of civil service uniform, probably sometime after 1870.

Comment: Its weird to think Postal Inspectors might be walking around with functional sabers at their hip.

Comment: Thank you to all that have responded so far.  I really appreciate it.
I cannot identify anyone in the photo, and it remains a complete mystery
to me.  My grandparents were born around 1908
in small towns near Bonn, Germany.  It sounds like you all feel this photo
was likely taken in Germany, and not in the USA, which could very well be
the case.  Would it be helpful if I posted a hi-res closeup image of the medal
on the man's chest, or any other part of the photo?  Thanks again!

Comment: @wjh33 - Yes please! Good things to get details of would be the medal, the shoulders, the cuffs, the buttons (yes, the buttons), and the saber hilt.

Comment: This seems like a parade uniform. Of note is the lack of a visible collar, most likely obscured by the man’s beard, the ceremonial sword, the trim on the arm sleeves as well as the fact that the man is wearing basic shoes and not some kind of boot or lower leg wrap that was a part of uniforms back then. Also, it’s a photo studio shot. The background is very flat, but up front you can see the objects people are sitting on are real. His arm is clearly resting on something physical. But if you look at the background, that is an outdoors scene but the front image is clearly indoors.

Comment: It would also be nice to see an enlarged version of the photos in the album on the lap of the young woman.

Comment: The [Langet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/langet) is not found on the common US swords, the [1850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_1850_Army_Staff_%26_Field_Officers%27_Sword) or [1902](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_1902_Army_Officers%27_Sword). It *is* a common feature on German swords-(see entry 9 in this incredibly informative [forum thread](https://www.warrelics.eu/forum/swords-german-reich-austria/german-sword-construction-478066/) ).

Comment: The medal looks like it could be a [War Commemorative Medal of 1870-1871](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Commemorative_Medal_of_1870-1871)?